# Drawing list of points in SDL?

Tags: c++, c, drawing, sdl

If i have an array of coordinates for a path(Such as in a paint program), what is the best way to render the entire path with SDL?

I looked at setting pixels individually, but from what i've seen that's a bad idea.

I also thought about drawing all the coordinates as SDL_Rect's, but rendering a large list of rect's each frame sounds slow.

Is there a simple way of achieving this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement yourself the [Bresenham line algorithm](http://www.webkinesia.com/games/sdl-turtle.php) directly accessing the framebuffer but I think you'll be doing much better using OpenGL...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SDL_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/software-mainmenu-14/4-ferzkopps-linux-software/19-sdlgfx).